# AWS Codepipeline not serving React from a PHP+React Git repository

Tags: php, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am new to AWS and I was creating a Codepipeline for my GIT repository. My frontend is in React and backend is in PHP. So first I created an elastic beanstalk environment for php as backend. Then used AWS codebuild to build my code and finaly created a code pipeline.

Now issue is, when I am trying to access the pipeline I can only see php in it. React frontend isn't loading.

At first I thought maybe my react code is not getting build so I changed little react code and i got it's update in aws codebuild. So, I guess that's not the problem.

Please let me know if anyone needs any specific detail, I'll update my question.

This is my yaml file.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    # runtime-versions:
    #   nodejs: 14.11.0
    commands:
      # - echo installing node 16 
      # - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash
      # - apt install -y nodejs
      # - echo installing Yarn...
      # -  curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg |  apt-key add -
      # - echo "curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main"
      # - apt install --no-install-recommends yarn
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install 
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Testing ...
      # yarn test
      - echo Building ...
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
# Include only the files required for your application to run.
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
base-directory : 'build'
    # - config.js
    # - index.js
    # - reset.js
    # - package.json
    # - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: Can you add your build yml files or more context to the problem?

Comment: @DreamBold, I have added it. Please have a look.